# How do you attach functionality to buttons in Embedded Elixir?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm rendering templates like so:

```
<%= for country <- @countries do %>
  <div>
    <div>A list of countries you have visited</div>
    <a href="/countries/<%= String.downcase(country) %>"><%= country %></a>
    <button> Click This </button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

in js of course I can do `<button onclick={myFunction}/>` but how do I do this in template world in elixir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoenix provides a lot of binding events which you can utilise in the phoenix based apps.

For e.g. if you want to call a function `on click` of a button then use the `phx-click` to call the function in the elixir module.

You can read more about the bindings.

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/bindings.html

Comment: Technically, `LiveView` had never been mentioned in the question.

Comment: Feel free to give `non live view` answer @Aleksei